# Does PartialViews share JS files if calls within a partialview?

Tags: c#, javascript, partial-views

If I have two partial views rendering to the same page and they both have JS files attached to it, will the js files interfere with each other because it is on the same page?

Comment: Yes, they are all scripts on the same page.  Indoect your page in a browser and look at the js.  You can use js patterns to encapsulate your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what the JS files do, and how they do it. But anyway, I recommend you to use somekind of asset manager like [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/) which will resolve alot of issues.

Comment: is there a way to isolate that partialview to do work with only that js file?  there is a possibility to have common infomation between the two partials but I want to isolate the js between the two

Comment: Ahm, not that I know of, the point of partial view is that it's content can be embbed to other pages.